# UpTo for negative indices?

Tags: list-manipulation

The symbol `UpTo` emerged as a sort of "safe take" in version 10:

```
Take[{1, 2, 3}, UpTo[4]]
(* Out: {1, 2, 3} *)
```

But it wasn't designed to handle negative indices or spans:

```
Take[{1, 2, 3}, UpTo[-4]]
(* Out: Take[{1, 2, 3}, UpTo[-4]] *)
```

Here's what I would expect the output to be:

```
Take[{1, 2, 3}, UpTo[-1]] (*  3        *)
Take[{1, 2, 3}, UpTo[-2]] (* {2, 3}    *)
Take[{1, 2, 3}, UpTo[-4]] (* {1, 2, 3} *)
```

Instead we get these errors:

> During evaluation of In[2]:= UpTo::innf: Non-negative integer or
>   Infinity expected at position 1 in UpTo[-4]. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[2]:= Take::seqs: Sequence specification (+n,
>   -n, {+n}, {-n}, {m, n}, or {m, n, s}) expected at position 2 in Take[{1,2,3},UpTo[-4]]. >>

It seems that `UpTo` is an inert wrapper. Is there anyway to overload `Take` to get this functionality?

Comment: Having `Take[{1, 2, 3}, UpTo[-4]]` not being evaluated is inconsistent with the behaviour of `UpTo`. This should return `{1, 2, 3}` as `UpTo[4]` would return. Correct?

Comment: Yes that's better

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update to use `UpTo`**

By `Unprotect`ing `UpTo` and adding an `UpValue` for `Negative` values.

```
Unprotect[UpTo];
UpTo /:
  Take[list_List, UpTo[n_Integer?Negative]] := list[[Max[-Length@list, n] ;;]];
Protect[UpTo];
```

Can also turn off the non-negative error message.

```
Off[UpTo::innf];
```

Then

```
Take[{1, 2, 3}, UpTo[-1]]
(* {3} *)

Take[{1, 2, 3}, UpTo[-10]]
(* {1, 2, 3} *)
```

---

**Original Post**

With `UpValues` on a new symbol `downTo`.

```
downTo /:
 Take[list_List, downTo[n_Integer?Negative]] := list[[Max[-Length@list, n] ;;]]
```

Then

```
Take[{1, 2, 3}, downTo[-1]]
(* {3} *)

Take[{1, 2, 3}, downTo[-3]]
(* {1, 2, 3} *)

Take[{1, 2, 3}, downTo[-10]]
(* {1, 2, 3} *)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did try this option already and it works nicely, but I'm hoping there is someway to overload UpTo, the reason being so that I don't have to special case my code.

Comment: I can only see unprotecting `UpTo` and assigning the above up value to it.

Comment: @M.R. Updated for overload of `UpTo` so that you don't have to change your code.  With the usual warnings on unprotecting an altering built-in functions.